# React canvas TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null after re-render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas, which uses the canvas.getContext( "2d" ) in ref.
my problem is that when the page re-renders, bc a state changes, I get an error and idk how to fix it.

this is a minimal code example where the error appears:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const Test: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState<number>( 0 );

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ () => { setCounter( counter + 1 ) } }>Test</button>
        <canvas ref={ canvas => {
            let context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
        } }/>
        </div>
    );
}

render( <Test />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

and this is the error:

```
canvas_test.component.tsx:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at ref (canvas_test.component.tsx:11)
    at commitDetachRef (react-dom.development.js:20893)
    at commitMutationEffects (react-dom.development.js:23348)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:23121)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:22990)
```

why does this error appear and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can init the canvas ref inside [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) which allows calling functions right after the component did mount or component update. (Right after the canvas element is available in the dom for us)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1);
        }}
      >
        Test
      </button>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs):

> React will call the `ref` callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and **call it with `null` when it unmounts**.

And as per [Caveats with callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs)

> If the `ref` callback is defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, first with `null` and then again with the DOM element.

I believe you are seeing the latter: each call to `setCounter` triggers an update, which, as per the above, calls your callback with `null`.

#### Solution

In your callback, handle the `null` condition. I'd recommend to also extract  the callback into its own function. Something like:

```
const Test: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState<number>( 0 );

    const refHandler = (canvas) => {
        if (!canvas) return;

        let context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ () => { setCounter( counter + 1 ) } }>Test</button>
        <canvas ref={refHandler} />
        </div>
    );
}
```